# Use kubectl via ssh bastion host do deploy from bitbucket pipelines

Tags: ssh, google-kubernetes-engine, bitbucket-pipelines, ssh-tunnel

We have two GKE private clusters, where access is only possible via ssh proxy.

In the local environment this works this way:

1. Open a ssh connection with port 8888 forwarding to the bastion host
   `gcloud compute ssh dev-cluster-bastion --project client-dev --zone xxxx -- -L 8888:127.0.0.1:8888`
2. In another session
   `HTTPS_PROXY=localhost:8888 kubectl get pods`

This returns the list of the running pods.

When we do this inside a bitbucket pipeline, then the ssh connects, but then closes and the `kubectl` call fails.
The message from the ssh connection is:

`Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal`

So the portforwarding is closed too.

Adding `-fN` to the ssh start does not help, the port forwarding is not working.

`gcloud compute ssh dev-cluster-bastion --project client-dev --zone xxxx -- -fN -L 8888:127.0.0.1:8888`

ssh then tells me `client_loop: send disconnect: Connection reset by peer`

Any ideas how to open the port 8888 tcp tunnel inside a bitbucket pipeline, so we can send the kubectl commands to the cluster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended way to use Google Cloud APIs in a non-interactive setting (like Bitbucket pipelines, GitHub actions, etc.) is to:

1. Create a [Service Account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts) , and refer to this  [link](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts)  for service account creation.
2. Create a key file for this service account and download it. Kindly refer to the [link](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys) for file creation.
3. Grant the needed IAM permissions to this account to be able to SSH into the Bastion host
4. Make the key file available to the pipeline environment *securely* (most CI/CD systems allow a way to encrypt secret files or sensitive environment variables)
5. In the pipeline, use `gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=...` to make `gcloud` use the service account
6. Now run `gcloud compute ssh` in the pipeline and use SSH port forwarding as usual.

Note that:

- steps 1.--4. are one time only;
- steps 5. and 6. are part of the pipeline and will run every time the pipeline is run
- The only difference being the presence of the `-fN` flags, which execute SSH in the background and make it run no command on the remote host (i.e. only do port forwarding).

You can also refer to  [Service account creation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/activate-service-account) and [Get started with Bitbucket-pipeline](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/get-started-with-bitbucket-pipelines/) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this error **Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal**. follow one of the below steps:

The error occurred because you're running SSH with a single -t option, when the standard input to the SSH process isn't a TTY. SSH prints that message specifically in this case A single -t is equivalent to "RequestTTY yes", while two of them is equivalent to "RequestTTY force".

If you want your remote command(s) to run with a TTY, then specify -t twice. If you are doing so then in your command instead of -t use -t -t or use -tt .

To fix this error **client_loop: send disconnect: Connection reset by peer**  follow the below steps:

You shall look on these parameters on the client
side **/etc/ssh/ssh_config**
**ServerAliveInterval**
**ServerAliveCountMax**
To set the interval to the value 60 and try
**ServerAliveInterval 60**

Comment: Not sure you did understand the problem, I don't wish to execute remote commands, I just need the port 8888 forwarding working, so the `kubectl` commands are sent to the remote target.

Comment: Unfortunally your solutions don't work